# ANTLR4 Context is empty with correct parsing order

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to parse conjunctive queries of the form:
"Answer(x,y,z):-R(x,y),U(y,z).".

Using Antlr4 in Java (Maven) I built the following grammar

```
grammar CQgrammar;

// Parser rules
query : head ':-' body;
head : atom;
body : atom (',' atom)* '.';
atom : ATOMNAME '(' term* (',' term)* ')';
term : CONST | VAR;

// Lexer rules
VAR: [a-z];
CONST: '"' [a-zA-Z0-9]+ '"';
TERMS: '(' | ')' | ',' | '.' | ':-';

ATOMNAME: [a-zA-Z0-9]+;
```

From this, I extend the generated listener class to override

1. enterQuery
2. enterHead
3. enterBody
4. enterAtom
5. enterTerm
   For now, I have simple printlns in these overrides, but the goal is to construct a conjunctive query class from this.

My main function is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String query = "Answer(x,y,z):-R(x,y),U(y,z).";
        org.parsing.CQgrammarLexer lexer = new org.parsing.CQgrammarLexer(CharStreams.fromString(query));
        org.parsing.CQgrammarParser parser = new org.parsing.CQgrammarParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));

        CQparser listener = new CQparser();
        parser.addParseListener(listener);
        parser.query();
    }
```

From the printlines in the overrides, I can see that the structure is correct, as in
each part of the query is entered in the correct order and there are no errors.

Yet, when I try to access the text in each override with ctx.getText(),
It is empty. Even the other getters on the ctx parameter such as ctx.Atom() in enterAtom
Is empty.

I believe something is wrong with the lexer part but the documentation is not very clear to me on this.
Does anyone know what I could do to fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: On entry, the children of a parse tree node all null because the parse tree is being constructed. The parse hasn't entered the recognition methods of the children. This is LL not LR. Run the tree walker after the parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally use a `ParseTreeWalker` to walk the parse tree. A quick demo:

```java
public class CQgrammarDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String query = "Answer(x,y,z):-R(x,y),U(y,z).";
        CQgrammarLexer lexer = new CQgrammarLexer(CharStreams.fromString(query));
        CQgrammarParser parser = new CQgrammarParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
        ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(new DemoListener(), parser.query());
    }
}

class DemoListener extends CQgrammarBaseListener {
    @Override
    public void enterTerm(CQgrammarParser.TermContext ctx) {
        System.out.println("const: " + ctx.CONST() + ", var: " + ctx.VAR());
    }
}
```

prints:

```
const: null, var: x
const: null, var: y
const: null, var: z
const: null, var: x
const: null, var: y
const: null, var: y
const: null, var: z
```